# How is the Heroism bonus meant to be applied?

Tags: microlite20

Microlite20 PDFs says:

> Heroism is a bonus equal to 1 times the characters level (1 at 1st, 2 at 2nd, et cetera) and may be applied once per day to up to three of the following

So, I have a +1 bonus at first level, +2 at second, etc. I can apply this bonus once per day. But is it before or after the roll? Or is it meant to be an ongoing bonus for the rest of the day?

Further on, what does "up to three of the following" mean? Might be my bad English, but I can't understand this. By "the following" the documentation provides this list:

> 1. Attack Bonus.
> 2. Damage.
> 3. Saving Throw.
> 4. Skill Check.
> 5. Spell DC

Does that mean I can apply this bonus to one attack, one damage roll and one skill check, but not to three skill checks? This list makes things more unclear by mentioning "Saving Throw", since, as far as I know, there are no saving throws in Microlite20.

I've tried to google this, but all I've found so far was [a confused wiki reader](http://microlite20.wikia.com/wiki/Heroism). So how are players supposed to apply this bonus?

Answer (score 2):

[Microluxe20](https://microluxe20.com/) project sheds some light upon this, rewording the Heroism feature description in a bit clearer way:

> **Heroism** is intended to relieve some of the power incompatibilities with some d20 adventure types. If you find that the party is
>   consistently too weak, try adding Heroism. **Heroism** is a bonus equal to 1 times the characters level (1 at 1st, 2 at 2nd, etc) and
>   may be applied to up to three of the following once per day: Attack Bonus, Damage, Saving Throw, Skill Check, Spell DC

So basically, you can add this bonus three times a day to any roll from the list provided, but you add only one bonus per roll. Presumably, you have to decide this *before* the roll is being made.